# Camel and Spring: stop context when route is completed

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to run a route once and stop the context when the route is completed. Currently I do the usual Thread.sleep(3000) in the main Java class to leave some time for the route to finish but it's obviously not accurate, my route may take 1 second or 20 seconds I can not know in advance.

The Java class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camel-context.xml")) {
        CamelContext camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(context);
        // context.start(); // apparently not necessary
        camelContext.startRoute("route1");
        try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        // context.stop(); // apparently not necessary
    }
}
```

The Spring xml:

```
<route id="route1" autoStartup="false">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=3000" />
    ...
</route>
```

After reading http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Need-control-back-in-the-Main-routine-so-that-we-can-terminate-JVM-td4483312.html#a4484845 especially the 4th post, from Claus Ibsen, I was thinking of using camelContext.getRouteStatus() in a loop with a Thread.sleep() but wherever I try to get the route status in the code (even after the Thread.sleep(3000)), the status is always "started". I don't know any other way to detect when the route is done.

What is the recommended way to stop the Camel context when a/all route(s) is/are completed, using Spring?

Answer (score 2):

The route will never stop because routes do not have `complete` state. They can just be started, stopped or paused. A route will always be running if it's in the started state unless you do something to change that.

To accomplish what you are looking for, you can do a couple of things:

- You can use the `controlbus` component and stop the route in the last step of your route. That way you can check (for example the way you mentioned checking for `camelContext.getRouteStatus()`) when you should stop the context as well.
- You can write a small `Processor` that whenever it receives an `Exchange` it will stop the `camelContext`. Once ready, you will add it to the last step of your route.
- Camel supports `onCompletion` callbacks, which can be equivalent to the option above. See the [camel page](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html).

Probably, the first option is the easiest for your use case, however I would go for the second option. It seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Actually I already have a processor at the end of the route so I would go with your second option, but I would still need the try { Thread.sleep(3000); } in the Main class with a big number right? Because as you can see in my code, even without context.stop() the context stops right away...

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant way would be to use a synchronisation mechanism provided by Java like CountDownLatch. Main thread will wait for the latch to be opened by the Route thread. Something like :

```
 CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
 camelContext.addRoutes(createRoute(latch));
```

and somewhere in the createRoute Method add a processor at the end of the route to open the latch. This worked perfectly for me.

```
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        latch.countDown();                                
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the Camel context once a route has been executed, you can rely on [`onCompletion`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/oncompletion.html) to perform a given task once the `Exchange` is complete, regardless of whether it was successful. If you want to go beyond that and only stop the Camel context once the `Exchange` is completed successfully, you will need to specify `onCompleteOnly`.

So according to the DSL used, assuming that you want to stop the context only on success, you can proceed as next:

**In Java DSL:**

Simply use a processor to stop the Camel context

```
from(...)
    .onCompletion().onCompleteOnly()
        .process(exchange -> exchange.getContext().stop())
    .end()
    ...
```

**In XML/YAML DSL:**

Stop the Camel context thanks to a [Simple language](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/languages/simple-language.html) script that can be executed with [the language component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/language-component.html).

```
<from uri="..."/>
<onCompletion onCompleteOnly="true">
    <to uri="language:simple:${camelContext.stop()}"/>
</onCompletion>
...
```

**NB:** *This approach can also be used with the Java DSL but you need to add `camel-language` to your classpath while you don't need any additional components with the other approach.*